# detener animacion manteniendo los estilos js

Tags: javascript

es posible que al cancelar la animación se puedan mantener los estilos en el momento que la animación había corrido.

```
var anima = Element.animate([
 {left:"0px"},
 {left:"100px"}
],{ duration:1000 });
setTimeout(()=>{anima.cancel();},500);
```

en el tiempo en el que corre la animación alcanza los 50px, pero al cancelar me pone de nuevo los 0px. Es posible que al cancelar la animación pase a los 50px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de cancelar la animación, tienes que usar el método `animation.commitStyles();`, éste método copia el estado final del objeto incluso después de que se removió la animación, tal como se ve en [la documentación de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/commitStyles). Tu código quedaría así:

```
var anima = Element.animate([
 {left:"0px"},
 {left:"100px"}
],{ duration:1000 });
setTimeout(()=>{anima.commitStyles(); anima.cancel();},500); //Se añadió el método Animation.commitStyles()
```